# Correspondence between ideals of $R$ and ideals of $\mathcal{M}_n(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

I'm stuck with the following problem.

If $R$ is an unitary ring and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a bijective correspondence which preserves the order given by the inclusion between $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, where 
 $$\mathcal{A}:=\big\{I \trianglelefteq   R : I \mathrm{\, \,ideal\,of\, \,} R \big\}   \rightleftarrows   \big\{ \mathfrak{a}\trianglelefteq\mathcal{M}_{n}(R): \mathfrak a   \mathrm{\,\,ideal\,of\,} \mathcal{M}_n(R)\big\}=:\mathcal{B}. $$

I was thinking in using the following "generalized" correspondence theorem, but I can't think of a suitable ring morphism from $R$ onto $\mathcal{M}_n(R)$
[image: Correspondence]

Also, my first attempt was to give an explicit function from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal B$, namely $F: I\mapsto \mathcal{M}_n(I):=\big\{ (a_{ij})\in \mathcal{M}_n(R): a_{ij}\in I\quad \forall i, j \big\}.$
This seems to work, but I can't find an explicit function from $G: \mathcal B \to \mathcal A$ which also serves as an inverse for $F$ ($GF=1_{\mathcal A}$ and $FG=1_{\mathcal B}$ ).

What do you think? Is it possible to use the theorem above? Is there a "painless" way to give such $G: \mathcal B \to \mathcal A$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know how to proof that $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ has no non-trivial ideals?

Answer (score 1):

The map $I\mapsto M_n(I)$ is clearly well defined and injective.

It remains to show that every ideal $J$ of $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(I)$, for some ideal $I$ in $R$.

Consider the *matrix unit* $E_{ij}$ defined as the matrix having $1$ at the place $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere. By suitably multiplying of a matrix $A=(a_{ij})\in J$ with matrix units on the left and on the right, show you can express
$$
A=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}E_{ij}
$$
and that $a_{ij}E_{ij}\in J$. Now consider the subset $I$ of $R$ consisting of those elements that appear in at least one matrix in $J$ and prove $J=M_n(I)$.

Comment: Ok, it seems quite reasonable, I will work on that idea!